# Moved wordpress dashboard still pointing to testing server

Tags: migration, wp-config

I uploaded my wordpress site to my testing server something like this: `201.99.1.11/mysite` for testing purpose and then downloaded complete root folder in my system, exported database and then uploaded it to my live server did setup database and in `wp-config.php` did setup username, password and db name also, Front-end of the site is working perfectly but when I try to login to dashboard it redirects me back to testing server.

Where should I make change to make sure I get logged in to my live version of the site instead of being redirected to testing version?

Answer (score 0):

The URLs are built from WordPress Address and Site Address in Settings > General. They are typically stored in database in `home` and `siteurl` options, but might also be overridden with configuration constants.

Codex has documentation on [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) that covers common scenarios.

Note that you might want to do a *global* replacement on database, since content might have persistently stored links to old URL and so on. Be aware that you need to use serialize-aware search/replace tool, not merely run text replace. WP CLI can do it.

Comment: i added these lines to wp-cofig.php what else ? define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');